# How to add time in sqlserver?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've two coloumns named Time_In and Grace_Time,which is in time format.I want to add these two columns.
I've used '+' operator but it doesnt works.Im getting the error like this

```
Operand data type time is invalid for add operator.
```

How can i do it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to cast them to datetime before add

```
CAST(Time_In AS DATETIME) + CAST(Grace_Time AS DATETIME)
```